# attempt to build the program titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium

I have a problem after installing the titanium studio. When I run the program, it has displayed this error and I can not know how to fix it.

I feel tired because it left me 2 days to fix it. someone, please help me. thank you very much

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2hPl.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK5oR.png)

Comment: Can you paste the error text in to the question, rather than making people click on a link to something non-searchable

Comment: I hope you mean appcelerator studio? Otherwise, Titanium Studio has been deprecated for 2 years. Also, run `appc info` on CLI and post result too